# Access elements of a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, array-broadcasting

I have the following TensorFlow tensors.

```
tensor1 = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,255, (2,512,512,1)), dtype='int32') #All elements in range [0,255]
tensor2 = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,255, (2,512,512,1)), dtype='int32') #All elements in range [0,255]

tensor3 = tf.keras.backend.flatten(tensor1)
tensor4 = tf.keras.backend.flatten(tensor2)

tensor5 = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,255, (255,255)), dtype='int32') #All elements in range [0,255]
```

I wish to use the values stored in tensor 3 and tensor 4 to make a tuple and query the element at position given by the tuple in tensor 5. For example, let's say 0th element in tensor 3, that is tensor3[0]=5 and tensor4[0]=99.
So the tuple becomes (5,99). I wish to look up the value of element (5,99) in tensor 5. I wish to do it for all elements in Tensor3 and Tensor4 in a batch processing manner. That is I do not want to loop over all values in the range of (len(Tensor3)). I did the following to achieve this.

```
tensor6 = tensor5[tensor3[0],tensor4[0]]
```

But tensor6 has the shape (255,255) where as I was hoping to get a tensor of shape (len(tensor3),len(tensor3)). I wanted to evaluate tensor5 at all possible locations in len(tensor3). That is at `(0,0),...(1000,1000),....(2000,2000),...`. I am using TensorFlow version 1.12.0. How can I achieve this?

Comment: in the last piece of code why haven't you included `tensor5[tensor3[0], tensor4[0]]`? I mean why are the indices not present?

Comment: Good catch, I fixed it in the question. However, I wish to evaluate `tensor5` for all corresponding pairs in `tensor3` and `tensor4`. For example for `(0,0),...,(1000,1000),...`So the length of output should
 be length of `tensor3`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: I am using TensorFlow 1.12

Comment: is it okay if I give you a solution for tf 2.x?

Comment: Yes, it is something to learn for me even though I cannot use it directly. I may try to write some custom functions to do the same in TensorFlow 1.12. So I do appreciate any solution you can suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get something working in Tensorflow v 1.12, but do let me know if it is the expected code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import numpy as np

tensor1 = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,255, (2,512,512,1)), dtype='int32') #All elements in range [0,255]
tensor2 = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,255, (2,512,512,1)), dtype='int32') #All elements in range [0,255]

tensor3 = tf.keras.backend.flatten(tensor1)
tensor4 = tf.keras.backend.flatten(tensor2)

tensor5 = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,255, (255,255)), dtype='int32') #All elements in range [0,255]

elems = (tensor3, tensor4)
a = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tensor5[x[0], x[1]], elems, dtype=tf.int32)

print(tf.Session().run(a))
```

Based on the comment below I'd like to add an explanation for the `map_fn` used in the code. Since `for` loops are not supported without eager_execution, `map_fn` is (sort of) equivalent to `for` loops.

A `map_fn` has the following parameters: `operation_performed`, `input_arguments`, `optional_dtype`. What happens under the hood is that a `for` loop is run along the length of the values in `input_arguments` (which must contain an iterable object) and then for each value obtained `operation_performed` is performed. For further clarification please refer [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn).

The names given to the arguments of the function is my way of interpreting them, as I'd like understand it, and is not given in the official docs. :)

Comment: It runs and it looks like it is ok. However, for me to make sure, can you please explain this line of code `a = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tensor5[x[0], x[1]], elems, dtype=tf.int32)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer and explanation.